# Index in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

The `Promise.all` method doesn't have an index to target a particular promise so in my case, I'm wondering if I can do this:

```
let promises = [Promise.resolve(true), 
                Promise.resolve(true), 
                Promise.resolve(false), 
                Promise.resolve(true)];

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    // [true, true, false, true]

    let failed = result.findIndex(r => !r);
    console.log(promises[failed]);

});
```

Now this is assuming the order is always maintained, i.e the result array is always in the same sequence as the input array?

Comment: Yes, the order will remains same in the same order you execute the promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Promise.all, the array returned will always be in the same order as the array provided, so you can safely use a set index.

Comment: How do you know? Is there an authoritative reference for this?

Comment: The MDN web docs are a good source of information for these types of questions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all